# ASP.NET 4 MVC - Partial View not found error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got this error, and I ensure I have the file `FormModelConfigurarAreaItem.cshtml` in the `EditorTemplates`.

No found the partial view  `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FormModelConfigurarAreaItem` or there are no search mottor which admits this path.

**The code is:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult BlankFormModelConfigurarAreaItem()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FormModelConfigurarAreaItem", new FormModelConfigurarAreaItem ());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **FormModelConfigurarAreaItem** is partial view name then you have to write full name with extenstion which is **FormModelConfigurarAreaItem.cshtml** for Razor Engine and **FormModelConfigurarAreaItem.ascx** for ASPX engine:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FormModelConfigurarAreaItem.cshtml", new FormModelConfigurarAreaItem ());
```